# How to trigger foreign key relation without adding a reference @Entity in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

The following relationship creates a foreign key mapping

```
@Entity
public class Department {
   @Id
   private String name;

   //some more fields
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
   @Id
   private long id;

   private String name;
   private String designation;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "fk_department_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_department"))
   private Department department;
}
```

generates:

> ...CONSTRAINT `fk_department` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_department_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`name`)

Question: how can I trigger this constraint creation in hibernate *without* having to create the `Department` entity?

Eg just adding the foreign key `@Id` field without an explicit entity reference. But still trigger the fk on initial creation. The following is of course invalid:

```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "fk_department_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_department"))
   private String department;
```

You get the intention. Is that possible?

(sidenote: I'm not interested in creating that foreign key link by startup ddl/sql statements).

Comment: So you want to create the schema from your entities, but you don't want to write your entities to match the schema?

Comment: Exactly, in this special case for that foreign table entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to drop `@ManyToOne` at least, since that's for entities.

The following should work by overriding the column definition to include the foreign key while creating it

```
@Column(name = "department_id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255), foreign key (department_id) REFERENCES department(name)")
private String department;
```

Now there's only a column and a constraint defined, but no relation (as far as Hibernate knows) defined between entities.

Essentially copied from [Hibernate and JPA: how to make a foreign key constraint on a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062194/hibernate-and-jpa-how-to-make-a-foreign-key-constraint-on-a-string) but that was darn hard to find, so I'm not just going to close this as a duplicate! ;)

Comment: Unfortunately as a result of this, no foreign key relation is created by hibernate!

Comment: @membersound how about this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using `mysql`, and that does not support inline foreign keys directly. To quote the docs: `MySQL does not recognize or support “inline REFERENCES specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification`. Therefore the column definition would have to be as follows: `@Column(name = "department_id", columnDefinition = "varchar(255), foreign key (department_id) REFERENCES department (name)")`. I tried this, it worked. BUT it feels somehow very very hacky...

Comment: Well your requirements are hacky. You've already said in your question that you don't want to use either of the 2 clean ways.

Comment: Ok you're probably right. So if there is no "cleaner" way this is probably the answer. Glad it works at all!